# Why are my tab views transparent?

Tags: android, android-layout

Working on the New Boston tutorials (I highly recommend them if you know anybody trying to learn android).  I'm currently working through tabs.  I have a few setup but you can see and interact with all tab contents behind the one "on top".  How do I stop that?  I tried adding a background in each of the linearlayouts that make up each tab but all that did was make them see through with different colored backgrounds.  The image at the bottom shows the left tab on top, but buttons/text views from the 2nd and 3rd tab showing through.  I need each tab to only show what in that tab, not in tabs behind the top one.

Java:

```
    package com.thenewboston.psest328;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Tabs extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        TabHost th;
        Button newTab, bStart, bStop;
        TextView showResults;
        long start;
        long stop;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

            th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
            newTab = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bAddTab);
            bStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStartWatch);
            bStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStopWatch);
            showResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvShowResults);
            th.setup();

            newTab.setOnClickListener(this);
            bStart.setOnClickListener(this);
            bStop.setOnClickListener(this);

            TabSpec spec = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
            spec.setIndicator("StopWatch");
            th.addTab(spec);

            spec = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
            spec.setIndicator("Tab 2");
            th.addTab(spec);

            spec = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
            spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
            spec.setIndicator("Add Tab");
            th.addTab(spec);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bAddTab:

            TabSpec ourSpec = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
            ourSpec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    TextView text = new TextView(Tabs.this);
                    text.setText("You've created a new tab");
                    return text;
                }
            });
            ourSpec.setIndicator("New");
            th.addTab(ourSpec);

            break;

        case R.id.bStartWatch:
            start = 0;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            break;

        case R.id.bStopWatch:
            stop = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if(start != 0) {
                long result = stop - start;
                showResults.setText(Long.toString(result));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bStartWatch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Start" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bStopWatch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Stop" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvShowResults"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView 3" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bAddTab"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Add Tab" />                    

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>    
</LinearLayout>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what the layout should look like, it's hard to advise. What you are seeing, however, is a side-effect of placing multiple items in a `FrameLayout` which basically allows overlays. As for transparency, most Android 'views' have a level of transparency by design - it's just you don't normally notice it until you overlay them.

Comment: @Squonk I've added to my main question.  The layout itself is good, but what you're seeing is the contents of all 3 tabs showing through.  I need it to only show whats in the current tab

Comment: In your `onCreate(...)` method where you create your `TabSpecs`, instead of re-using `spec` try using 3 different `TabSpec` objects. In other words...`TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("tag1");` then `TabSpec spec2 = ...` and `TabSpec spec3 = ...`

Comment: @Squonk Just tried it, no luck

Comment: Sorry I don't have any other ideas although this is a link to a Tabbed app example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android - perhaps try following the layout structure in that. It puts `TabHost` as the root view rather than putting it in a `LinearLayout` as you've done.